# ORDER BY across multiple columns in Postgres SQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sql-order-by

As an example let's consider the following Table `players` in a Postgres SQL database

```
name            username*        score*
--------------------------------------
Jack Daniels    PerfectJack      100
-               JohnDoe          20
-               MadMike          500
Ben Tailor      Tailor3d         10

(* = required)
```

I want to query that table and output the following (pseudocode)

```
SELECT (ISSET name ? name : username, score) 
FROM players 
ORDER BY (ISSET name ? name : username)
```

which should result in

```
player         score
--------------------
Ben Tailor     10
Jack Daniels   100
JohnDoe        20
MadMike        500
```

For clarification: Let's assume a webapp where the user signs up with a username. He MAY also enter his real name, but is not required to. When showing a list of players, the webapp should be able to output the real name (if set) and fallback to the username (if name is not set) and order across those two columns (i.e. use the real name if available for ordering, otherwise use the username).

How can this behaviour be achieved with an Postgres SQL statement?

Comment: You can use case statements in order by clause

Comment: @michel.milezzi: Why did you remove the my-sql-tag? As far as I can see, COALESCE also works with MySQL as well!? https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Comment: Yes, it'll works on MySQL too. Because you said "How can this behaviour be achieved with an Postgres SQL statement?". Regards!

Comment: Gotcha! Since it works with mysql as well, it might make sense to keep the tag in my opinion as others (even if searching for a mysql-solution instead of postgres) might find this answer helpful as well. Hence I vote for keeping the tag :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#functions-coalesce-nvl-ifnull):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(name, username) AS player, 
    score 
FROM 
    players 
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(name, username);
```

Also, avoid using reserved words - such "name" - in yours objects.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT case when name is not null then name else username end player, score
FROM players 
ORDER BY case when name is not null then name else username end
```

Comment: Are you missing an as here? -> `SELECT case when name is not null then name else username end **AS** player`

Comment: @Christian PostgreSQL allow ommiting this keyword when defining column aliases

Comment: Thanks for this explanation!